# How do I display only the text user has written from component to another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

After I'm done creating an article via `CreateArticle` component (which works fine), I want to display only what the user has written (its `value`) in `<textarea value={value}>` in the `SearchArticle` component via `displayName()` function.

In other words, in `CreateArticle` component when the user's done typing something in `<textarea/>` followed by clicking `Submit` (which's a button that saves what the user wrote), I want to only display what the user has written in `Search Article` inside `displayName()` function.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `CreateArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import * as actionType from "../../store/actions/actions";

class CreateArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        this.setState({storyTextValue: event.target.value});
        this.props.storyTextValueRedux(event.target.storyTextValue);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    handleStoryText = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    onSubmit = () => {
        if(this.state.value === "") {
            alert("Please enter the value and then click submit");
        } else {
            alert("Article saved " + '\n' + this.state.value + this.props.articleIdValue);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="author name"/>
                    <textarea value={this.props.storyTextValue} onChange={this.handleStoryText} rows="2" cols="25" />
                    <button type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={() => this.onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value}),
        storyTextValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.STORY_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateArticle);
```

Here's `SearchArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionType from '../../store/actions/actions';

import ArticleText from '../../containers/ArticleText/ArticleText';

class SearchArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            flag: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.CityCodeReducerRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({flag: true});
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    displayName = () => {
        if(this.props.cityCodeValue === "nyc" || this.props.articleIdValue === 1) {
            return(
                <div>
                    <p>author name: {this.props.authorNameValue}</p>
                    <p>article text: {<ArticleText/>}</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.articleIdValue} placeholder="article id"/>
                    <button onClick={() => this.displayName}  value="Search">Submit</button>
                    {this.state.flag ? this.displayName() : null}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cityCodeValue: state.cityCodeValue.cityCodeValue,
        authorNameValue: state.authorNameValue.authorNameValue,
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        CityCodeReducerRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE, value}),
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchArticle);
```

Here's `StoryTextReducer`:

```
import * as actionType from '../store/actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    storyTextValue: ''
};

const StoryTextReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.STORY_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                storyTextValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default StoryTextReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at 2 different instances of `<ArticleText>`. Changing properties of the instance in `CreateArticle` will not change the instance in `SearchArticle`

Instead of trying to share a value by using the same class, you should be sharing a value by whats in the redux store.

You should define an action that dispatches and event like `{type: updateArticleText, articleText: foo}`, then in your reducer you can set the redux state to have a property `ArticleText` equal to event.articleText.

Now that your value is stored in redux store rather than component state, your components simply get props from the redux store in the `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: I've included `StoryTextReducer ` in my original post.  Would that way be correct?

Comment: Looks fine, you will need to add the `storyTextValue` in your `mapStateToProps` where you want to now display the value

Comment: hmm ok.  In `CreateArticle`  I did what you said with `storyTextValue ` and `mapStateToProps `  but `this.state = {
            value: ''
        }` is a problem because the way the user is writing (and saving) the text is dependent on   `this.state = {
            value: ''
        }`.  If I change up `<textarea value={value}` to `<textarea value ={this.props.storyTextValue}`, then whenever the user types something in the box,  the `alert()` comes up.

Comment: you will need to fire the action to update `storyTextValue` when user types, you shouldn't need `this.state.value` anymore

Comment: I changed up `handleSubmit()`, may you please check it?

Comment: Looks fine, still don't need this.state

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180755/discussion-between-sp92-and-stackoverfloweth).